# What else was in the Ark (Teiva)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, mabul

I heard that there is a Medrash that says that besides Noach, his wife, 3 sons, 3 daughters-in-law, animals, birds, and garbage there were others in the Teiva. What else was in the Teiva?

Comment: What makes you think that anything else was?

Comment: I was told that there is a Medrash that discusses this, although I as of yet have not been able to find it.

Comment: Your question would be enhanced if you would include that information in it. The more information in the question, even "I heard there's a midrash somewhere," the more likely it will get good answers, and the more useful it is to the Googling public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Midrash Rabbah](http://www.archive.org/stream/midrashrabbahgen027557mbp#page/n293/mode/2up)

- pressed Figs (the greater part of his provisions)
- branches (for the elephants)
- hazubah (a shrub for the deer)
- glass (for the ostriches [probably to aid their digestion?])
- vines and shoots for planting (fig, olive, [grape](http://www.archive.org/stream/midrashrabbahgen027557mbp#page/n335/mode/2up))
- young [Re'ems](http://www.archive.org/stream/midrashrabbahgen027557mbp#page/n293/mode/2up)
- a luminous, polished gem stone ("[zohar](http://www.archive.org/stream/midrashrabbahgen027557mbp#page/n291/mode/2up)")

Answer (score 5):

There were 'mazikim' that entered the teiva (Rashi, 6:19)

also Og the king of Bashan was holding the teiva from outside and was swimming on it like on a float (or was sitting on it)

Comment: There was also a Re'em outside the Teiva.

Comment: The is a description of number of big animals in the beggining of fifth perek in Baba Batra (like הררי אלף also) that couldn't get into the Teiva because of theirs sizes. But I've heard an explanation is that all that gemorah is not "כפשותו" and has a kabbalistic explanation, so also the Re'em maybe not a real animal, but rather a hint to some spiritual idea

Answer (score 4):

Besides for the Pair of Ravens the Netziv says that Noach had a Private raven. This was apparently the way of royalty to have one raven and one dove.

Comment: What is the source of this?

Comment: as it states clearly the Netziv

Answer (score 4):

Both Rabeinu Bachai (Bamidbar 21:34) and the Maharsha (Nidda 61A) say that Cham's wife committed adultery with Shamchzi and then gave birth to Sichon (Og's brother) in the teivah.

Answer (score 3):

Just found a Yalkut Shimoni on Parshas Noach that mentions that Sheker wanted to come into the Teiva. Noach would not let him in as he had no pair. So Sheker cut a deal with Pichsa (tragedy) to join him in the Teiva. In exchange they made up that anything earned through Sheker would have a tragic end.

Comment: This is very true! Anything got with Sheker, a lie, will end in tragedy. It always does.

Answer (score 1):

Food, but that's not a medrash.

Comment: Something about some Malachim?

Comment: And of course seeds.